Each K-number returns too many values in the openfda.registration_number column
Thank you very much for your attention.
I found there are too many values matched with each Knumber in the openfda.registration_number column. It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me understand why this discrepancy exists and how I should interpret the data. I have downloaded Device 510(k) through this URL (https://open.fda.gov/data/downloads/).

For example, K212116 has more than 20 registration_numbers (e.g., 3031194398, 8043933, 3013410552, and 3007545404). This seems strange because the applicant of K212116 is VYSIONEER INC, which has two Registration Numbers: 3020648836 and 3020978043.
Other registration_numbers are linked to different firms (e.g., 3031194398 is linked to WISDOM TECHNOLOGIES, INC.; 8043933 is linked to BRAINLAB AG).

